# Burninate [database-managers]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I came across [database-managers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database-managers). This term is very vague.

Some info:

- 9 questions, 5 closed, [others](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdatabase-managers%5D%20closed%3Ano) deserve to be closed or retagged
- No wiki and excerpt
- Looks like it was created to tag questions about asking for recommendations of database managers for various databases.

I see no reason we should keep this tag. If somebody has a question about particular database manager, he should use specific tag (like [phpmyadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phpmyadmin), [pgadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pgadmin), [mysql-workbench](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-workbench), [heidisql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/heidisql), etc).

Comment: So we tried to get rid of the [project managers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project-management) and now the databases are next ...

Comment: I deleted the remaining 3 very old closed questions with <1k views and link only answers. Can't see any other question left there.

Comment: suggested title -  "Fire the [database-managers]"

Comment: @BhargavRao Somebody deleted or retagged other questions before you

Comment: Ah, ok. "[database-managers] deleted:all" returns only those which I deleted, so I guess someone else must have retagged them.  Anyway, now the tag is empty and would be dead by tomo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been solved.

Some questions have been deleted and others were retagged.

Comment: Please do not retag closed questions that can be deleted next time. Mod can do it easily, and we'll get rid of them.